# Only returns 1 row?

Tags: mysql, netbeans

[image: This is the table containing the data]

[image: This is my command]

Picture 1 is the table containing the data

Picture 2 is my command

Why is it only returning 1 row and not the same for all the subjectIDs?
How do I make it return a row for each subjectID?
Thanks

p.s Please keep things simple I need to do this with basic sql.

Comment: Thank you Kevin!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running an `AVG` command. This will aggregate the results, since an average has to be run on multiple rows of data.

If you want to have it grouped in a different way, you can do this with a `GROUP BY` clause. This will return a row for every distinct values for the column(s) specified in the `GROUP BY` clause, with the calculated average and so on.

It would look similar to the following:

```
SELECT subjectid, AVG(result)
FROM Results
GROUP BY subjectid
```